# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^p\sin x}{1+x^q}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Considering convergence and semi-convergence integral following:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^p\sin x}{1+x^q}dx$$

I don't know how!

Submit your solution! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Submit your solution there? Is there a contest?

Comment: Not to mention: what is semi-convergence? What is $p$? What is $q?$

Comment: For $p=1$ and $q=2$ we have $I=\displaystyle\frac\pi{2e}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{red}{Hint}:$$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^p\sin x}{1+x^q}dx=(\underbrace{\int_0^c\frac{x^p\sin x}{1+x^q}dx}_{ p+1-q\gt0}+\underbrace{\int_c^\infty \frac{x^p\sin x}{1+x^q}dx}_{p-q\lt0}$$

$$\begin{cases}
p-q\lt0 & \\\
p+1-q\gt0  &  \\
\end{cases}
\to -1\lt p-q\lt 0$$
answer is true for all $p,q\in \mathbb Z$ such that satisfied  in $-1\lt p-q\lt 0$}

Comment: Why do you have such a result?

Comment: @Mrnhan: for more detail see here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: Hedyello: But, when $p\leq -1$ then the integral doesn't convergence!

Comment: I think that $p> -1$ and $q-p>1$ then convergence integral!

Comment: @Mrnhan:dear i edit only for u i know this is homework but

Answer (score 1):

Are there p and q positive ? I think from 0 to 1 it converges iff the integral of X^p+1/1+x^q converges . .From 1 to infinite you can take absolute value and compare with  the integral of x^p-q in some cases ( q-p >1). But these are only some ideas.